# Sortable/filterable web table which can be updated without always losing selection/focus

Tags: library, javascript, web-development, react, vue.js

I have an older web app with a data table which every 5 seconds gets updated and has its contents refreshed (think of a process manager).

The table also allows sorting and filtering per row. But while the currently used library (jQuery tablesorter) allows for updating the table contents with the current sorting/filtering persisting, it still does so in a way that any current selection is lost with each data refresh, i.e. every 5 seconds, since it tries to resort all elements by removing and re-adding them to the DOM. (The same goes for the focus of interactive elements inside the cells.)

Now I am looking for a smarter solution, i.e. where the user selection is not lost if a refresh is happening, or at least only if the actual sorting order changes.

I guess a logical and up-to-date solution would involve a data table component in a virtual DOM framework like Vue.js or React, but in that case which one?